# Are there any IAU members on the astronomy stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

Are there any members of the International Astronomical Union that are active on  the Astronomy Stack Exchange?

Comment: At least [none of them have that information in their profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/1196859).

Comment: It is not considered good behavior to ask members for personal information, like if they are a member or a particular organization.  Note this could be interpreted as "phishing".  As you don't provide any profile info yourself it's doubly inappropriate to ask others for personal info.

Comment: Are you a republican? I have some questions...

Comment: Nice one, @RobJeffries.

Comment: Closing the question prevents people from posting answers. Considering that (at least) one user has already posted a well-received answer, closing is a bad idea. **voting to leave open!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am an IAU Member but a lot of professional astronomers, particularly junior scientists, aren't. The membership rules are slightly weird/archaic. You can only apply to join every three years when they are going to be holding the General Assembly ([Past General Assemblies](https://www.iau.org/science/meetings/past/general_assemblies/), next [General Assembly](https://www.iau.org/science/meetings/future/general_assemblies/1181/) will be in Busan, Korea in 2021). You have to submit a [qualified application](https://www.iau.org/administration/membership/individual/qualification/) to the national astronomy body in the country you are practicing astronomy in, normally with a deadline of ~December in the previous year. (For me this meant to the National Academies as the USA National Committee for Astronomy (NCA) even though I am British and got my Astronomy PhD in the UK).