# Create a wiki entry for future Starlink launches?

Tags: discussion

With the recent 2020-03-18 delayed-from-Sunday launch of the latest SpaceX mission for the build-out of the Starlink constellation, I am expecting another round of the "what is this set of bright lights moving in the sky" questions. Indeed [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35521/stars-moving-in-line-and-some-moves-around) seems to be the start of this new round.

With the expected possible launch schedule of up to [20 Starlink launches in 2020](https://spacenews.com/starlinks-busy-launch-schedule-is-workable-says-45th-space-wing/) alone, this could mean a lot of these type of questions every few weeks as the satellites are launched and before they spread out and move up to operating altitude. Can we create a wiki article and/or a bot that redirects these sort of questions to a table with the launch schedule and a "if you see a set of bright lights within X days of a launch date in this table, it's Starlink satellites" auto-answer ?

Comment: I think a CW Q&A that we can close them as duplicates of is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good idea!

A related concern was expressed in [Do we need a notice about billionaire space ventures?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/545/7982)

I guess the next step (once a community "yes" was established here) would be to ask the next question "What would the question be exactly?" but I also suspect that considering your intrinsic familiarity with the topic being a ["card-carrying" member of the IAU](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/573/7982) and [the last person to see an earlier SpaceX stunt](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/when-was-the-last-time-that-starman-roadster-was-seen/29958#comment95791_30453) , if you just wrote a question in the main site and opened a Wiki answer, in this particular case it would be fine.

*[If you build it, they will come](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Field_of_Dreams)*